# How to list random numbers for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created an insert into with a select table where what I want it to do is give a random 'PlayerWeighting for each player between 0-99. However the problem I have is that instead of randomizing a player weighting for each row, it seems to do it for each team a player is in. For example:

```
PlayerID   FirstName     Surname     PlayerWeighting  TeamID
1          Chelsea       Player1     87               1
2          Chelsea       Player2     87               1
3          Chelsea       Player3     87               1
4          Liverpool     Player1     73               2
5          Liverpool     Player2     73               2
```

I instead want it to do something like this:

```
PlayerID   FirstName     Surname     PlayerWeighting  TeamID
1          Chelsea       Player1     87               1
2          Chelsea       Player2     73               1
3          Chelsea       Player3     62               1
4          Liverpool     Player1     90               2
5          Liverpool     Player2     51               2
```

What do I need to change in my query for this to work (NumberID is the number at the end of each string for 'Player'?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Player_CreateWholeTeam]
    @TeamID INT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO dbo.Player (FirstName, Surname, PlayerWeighting, TeamID)
    SELECT TeamName AS FirstName, 'Player' + cast(NumberID AS VARCHAR (10)) AS Surname, CONVERT(INT, (RAND() * 99)) AS PlayerWeighting, @TeamID
        FROM dbo.Team t
        CROSS JOIN dbo.Number n
        WHERE TeamID = @TeamID
        AND n.NumberID <= 20

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will gives you random integer between 0 and 99

```
abs(convert (bigint, convert(varbinary(20), newid()))) % 100
```

or

```
abs(checksum(newid())) % 100
```

they key is to use NEWID(), it will generate a unique value for each row. RAND() does not

Comment: Thank you very much Squirrel